# How to remove repeating string occurrences from string property

Tags: javascript, object

I have a simple object

```
    {
    "totalMinutes": "00:01",
    "exception": "Yes",
    "observation": [],
    "zone": "Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 1, Zone 7, Zone 1, Zone 8, Zone 20, Zone 1, Zone 1",
    "startTime": "2023-01-03T06:22:17.298Z",
    "appVersion": "5.11.11",
    "month": "January",
    "userName": "Geeta Ammanola",
    "endLatlong": "0,0",
    "activity": "Rapid Tour",
    "profile": "Field Supervisor",
    "date": "20230103",
    "endTime": "2023-01-03T06:23:49.526Z",
    "status": "ABORTED",
    "rapidTourId": "bOiOmARnl7I8lGw1UAxN",
    "actualBOGHour": "00:01",
    "email": "geeta.ammanola.ext1@holcim.com",
    "intermediateBarcodeScanned": [],
    "region": "Asia",
    "opco": "Holcim Australia",
    "plant": "5010 Milton Concrete",
    "role": "country_admin",
    "bogMinutes": 20
}
```

I want to remove repeating string of property `zone` as `zone 1` is repeating string

```
{"zone": "Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 7, Zone 8, Zone 20"}
```

I tried to use `replace()` string but from it but it didn't workout as it is dynamic data.

can someone please help with this small issue?

Comment: `new Set("Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 7, Zone 8, Zone 20, Zone 20, Zone 20, Zone 20".replaceAll("Zone ", "").split(", "))`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+remove+duplicate+words+in+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please don't re-post, even if question is closed.  I was about to reply to your question from your previous post and even flagged to re-open after you gave more details, and then you deleted it.  You have rep score of 1273, so you really should know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const s = 'Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 1, Zone 7, Zone 1, Zone 8, Zone 20, Zone 1, Zone 1'

console.log([...new Set(s.split(', '))].join(', '))
```

Comment: Massive dupe...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `Set` to take care of duplicates for you

```js
let a = {
    "totalMinutes": "00:01",
    "zone": "Zone 4, Zone 1, Zone 1, Zone 7, Zone 1, Zone 8, Zone 20, Zone 1, Zone 1",
     "remaining properties...": "values..."
}

let inputArray = a.zone.split(", ");
let uniqueZones = [...new Set(inputArray)]
let output = uniqueZones.join(", ")
console.log(output)
```